# How do you configure the location of TeamCity server cache and temp directories?

Tags: teamcity, teamcity-9.0

[This blog post](https://blog.jetbrains.com/teamcity/2011/09/improving-performance-and-scalability-of-your-teamcity-server/) indicates that it's possible to re-configure the locations of the $data/system/caches and $server/temp directories in order to optimise a TeamCity installation.

Admittedly the post is a bit outdated; but I've done plenty of searching around and tweaking and can find no direct references on how to do this.

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

At the moment the only way is to map the directories to the desired location using OS-specific means (using symlinks). The related ticket in TeamCity bug tracker: [TW-15251](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-15251), please comment/watch it to get status updates.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there's no way to configure those directories locations on the TeamCity side. However, one can make use of OS-provided file system links to map the `$data/system/caches` and `$server/temp directories` to other locations, as documentation suggests doing for the `artifacts` directory ("Recommendations as to choosing Data Directory Location" section [here](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/TeamCity+Data+Directory))